# Redirect to php script

Tags: php, redirect

Could you help to make redirect on php script. For example if go to http://domain.com/dir/subdir/ .htaccess will move me to php script with get request like http://domain.com/index.php?url=/dir/subdir/ 
Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Are you asking how to use .htaccess to rewrite requests? If so, can you provide your current contents of .htaccess and what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write this in your .htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
#.htaccess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ index.php
```

Now you can extract the arbitrary URL parameters in your index.php?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?url=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: you should add what the L and R are doing

Comment: That means it is the Last rewrite rule and stops looping and/or conflicts. And R is for redirect